# Data column inputCol has not been analyzed yet, cannot run TF on this dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to use universal sentence encoder as a TFTransformer for a text analytics pipeline in spark. Code for creating TFTransformer from the tensor flow graph is given below.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from sparkdl import TFTransformer
from sparkdl.graph.input import TFInputGraph
import sparkdl.graph.utils as tfx
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3")
  text = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None], name='textinput')
  embedding = module(text)
  init_op = tf.group([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    gin = TFInputGraph.fromGraph(sess.graph, sess, ["textinput:0'"], ["module_apply_default/Encoder_en/hidden_layers/l2_normalize:0"])

transformer = TFTransformer(
    tfInputGraph=gin,
    inputMapping={'inputCol': tfx.tensor_name("textinput:0")},
    outputMapping={tfx.tensor_name("module_apply_default/Encoder_en/hidden_layers/l2_normalize:0"): 'outputCol'})

rows = [Row(inputCol=["how are you"]), Row(inputCol=["what are you upto"])]
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(rows)
odf = transformer.transform(sdf)
```

However, I am getting the following error

```java
java.lang.Exception: Data column inputCol has not been analyzed yet, cannot run TF on this dataframe
    at org.tensorframes.impl.DebugRowOps$$anonfun$26$$anonfun$27.apply(DebugRowOps.scala:329)
    at org.tensorframes.impl.DebugRowOps$$anonfun$26$$anonfun$27.apply(DebugRowOps.scala:329)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.tensorframes.impl.DebugRowOps$$anonfun$26.apply(DebugRowOps.scala:328)
    at org.tensorframes.impl.DebugRowOps$$anonfun$26.apply(DebugRowOps.scala:320)
```

Not sure what do we mean my "analyzed" data frame